# Is there a way to set an audio file's sample size in bytes using librosa?

Tags: python, audio, librosa, pydub

In `AudioSegment` from `from pydub import AudioSegment`, there is a function `set_sample_width`. From the docs:

> Creates an equivalent version of this AudioSegment with the specified sample width (in bytes). Increasing this value does not generally cause a reduction in quality. Reducing it definitely does cause a loss in quality. Higher Sample width means more dynamic range.

Is there similar functionality in librosa? I would like to set it to a certain value using librosa (and not pydub) if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is No.

Here's the longer answer:

librosa always uses floats to represent audio regardless of what the original bit depth was or how you are going to save it.

From the [docs](https://librosa.org/librosa/master/generated/librosa.core.load.html):

> Load an audio file as a floating point time series.

You can however specify a datatype via the `dtype` parameter. Then librosa (who delegates loading typically to [SoundFile](https://pypi.org/project/SoundFile/)) can also represent the audio as some kind of int.

Once you have loaded the audio, you can of course manually convert it to a different bit depth, by scaling to a different range that corresponds to whatever your desired bit depth may be.

Your last chance to change bit depth is when you save the audio data to a file. The librosa docs recommend to use [SoundFile write()](https://pysoundfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#soundfile.write) for this. It also lets you specify the datatype (to a degree):

> The data type of data does not select the data type of the written file. Audio data will be converted to the given subtype. Writing int values to a float file will not scale the values to `[-1.0, 1.0)`. If you write the value `np.array([42], dtype='int32')`, to a `subtype='FLOAT'` file, the file will then contain `np.array([42.], dtype='float32')`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Hendrik, thanks for your reply. I was hoping you could help me with something: is there a reason that when I write a time series (y) using `soundfile` with a `dtype=float32`, when I read it again (using soundfile), I get a `dtype=float64`? I specified in the read function that `dtype=None` so that it does not load a float64 by default. Any reasons there?